# DataTable Filtering

Tags: c#, datagrid, rowfilter, defaultview

I have a method that gets a list of numbers and filters my datatable according to it.

I use this code:

```
string MyQuery = CreateQueryMethod(MyNumbersList);
MyDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = MyQuery;
```

But if I get an empty list, MyQuery is just: ""   // (string.empty)
and if RowFilter is an empty string it shows the entire datatable - not filtered at all.

I want the datatable to be filtered to nothing in this case (I don't want to see any rows)
what do I give RowFilter in order to get an empty datatable?

Answer (score 2):

You can put a filter that is always false (e.g. column1 != column1).

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code I use to filter a dataTable and transform the filtered results back to a table...

```
 DataTable Table = (Loaded from database)
 DataView view = Table.DefaultView;
 view.RowFilter = string.Format("ColumnName={0}", numericValue);
 DataTable FilteredTable = view.ToTable();
```